# Where do plugin variables live in the db?

Tags: plugins, database

I'm no developer, rather a designer.  But for my wife, I'll be all things (this is for her free e-comm, erp, and crm solution[image])

So, i'm connecting dolibarr to woo com.  i need to double check the entry of the highlighted field.  that sucker needs to exist in the database somewhere...but i can't find it.

I looked in active plugins but thats not giving what i need.  anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Where to store plugin settings in the database is technically up to the plugin developer. I've seen some plugins that create custom database tables.

The *standardized* method, however, is to use the WordPress site options table (i.e. `wp_options`). That's what will be used if the developer uses the WordPress settings API.

You can view a list of all of the saved options if you visit `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/options.php`.

Many plugin developers don't do a single setting per database field, though. Instead, they save an array of settings into the database field. That means that if you try to view them on the `options.php` page,  you'll just see `SERIALIZED DATA` in the field. If you try to view the field in something like phpMyAdmin, you'll see a bunch of curly braces, colons, and numbers that are organizing the data. If you plan to modify them directly in the database, I'd recommend you do some research in to PHP data serialization before doing so.